# Rollapplyr and duplicated values

Tags: r, duplicates, flags, moving-average, rollapply

I want to find duplicated elements and flag them in a rolling window. Does anyone know how to do it in r? For example, assume that I want to check whether *value* is repeated in the following 2 rows. I want to get something like this:

| row_number | value | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | TRUE |
| 2 | 2 | FALSE |
| 3 | 1 | FALSE |
| 4 | 3 | FALSE |
| 5 | 2 | TRUE |
| 6 | 6 | FALSE |
| 6 | 2 | FALSE |

Comment: If this is rolling, is your window length "2"? If yes, why is row 5 true, the `2` is not the same as `3` (preceding) or `6` (following)?

Comment: Lacking that, `c(diff(yourdata$value) == 0, FALSE)` might be a good start.